# Pandas - Apply a function to a dataframe with several arguments from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I would like to use apply() function to a dataframe to generate a date range thanks to pandas date_range() function.

The following code works, and does what I expect it to do.

```
import pandas as pd

def my_date_range(start, end, freq):
    return pd.date_range(start = start, end = end, freq = freq)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start':[pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:00:00')], 'End':[pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:30:00')], 'Freq':[pd.Timedelta(5,'m')]})

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: my_date_range(x.Start, x.End, x.Freq), axis=1)
```

The result:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
       Start                 End     Freq
0 1970-01-02 1970-01-02 00:30:00 00:05:00

In[29] : df1[0]
Out[29]: 
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-02 00:00:00', '1970-01-02 00:05:00',
               '1970-01-02 00:10:00', '1970-01-02 00:15:00',
               '1970-01-02 00:20:00', '1970-01-02 00:25:00',
               '1970-01-02 00:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5T')
```

So now my problem / my questions.
I could read that it is possible to use apply() without lambda in this way, as I understand:

```
df2 = df[['Start', 'End', 'Freq']].apply(my_date_range, axis=1)
```

But above code produces following error.

```
TypeError: ("my_date_range() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'end' and 'freq'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

And is it interesting to avoid the use of lambda? (better performances?)

Finally, is there also a way to use directly pd.date_range?

If I try with below code, I get the following error:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.Start, x.End, x.Freq), axis=1)

"periods must be a number, got {periods}".format(periods=periods)

TypeError: ('periods must be a number, got 0 days 00:05:00', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1

As you can see in the error message, if you want to use the function name to `pandas.DataFrame.apply`, the function should take a `pandas.Series` as a argument. So it should be like this.

```
def my_date_range(x):
    return pd.date_range(start = x.Start, end = x.End, freq = x.Freq)
df2 = df.apply(my_date_range, axis=1)
```

#### 2

Well personally I think lambda makes things a lot more convenient. In your case, the original way you used of defining a function and then using another lambda is not convenient at all, since the point of `lambda` is not having to use `def`. However you can use lambda and make it more convenient as you tried in the last part of the question.

#### 3

The reason of the error is because the function `pd.date_range` arguments goes like this.
`pandas.date_range(start=None, end=None, periods=None, ...)` So if you just give it as a positional argument as you did, it thinks the third argument is `period=`. You should give it as a keyword argument (as you did in above).

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start = x.Start, end = x.End, freq = x.Freq), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
start = pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:30:00')
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5Min')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The example is voluntary simplified, but I do want to apply the date_range function on a dataframe, not single distinct values.